# Razor MVC server side custom validation C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have a simple question,
I have two fields in my table which I need to check whether they exist in database or not before storing..
**In My Model**

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Contract Type")]
public int tb_contract_type_id { get; set; } //This is drop-down box

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Domain Name")]
public string domain_name { get; set; } //this is text-box
```

These two properties I need to check in database whether they exist or not,
If they wont exist then only we need allow the user to add the data otherwise not.

**I have done this for for one field like below,Now I want to check to do for two fields like 
db.contracts.Any(c => c.domain_name == URL && tb_contract_type_id == id )**

**From model**

```
 [CheckForDomain]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Domain Name")]
    public string domain_name { get; set; }
...
public class CheckForDomain : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private DataContext db = new DataContext();
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid
          (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            var URL = value.ToString();
            if (db.contracts.Any(c => c.domain_name == URL ))
            {
                return new ValidationResult("Domain Name already Exist!!");
            }
            else
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there any good way to check that using Custom validation?
I'm using Entity framework
Kindly suggest..

Comment: Could you give us more details about what do you want to achieve? And give us sample of code where you want it/

Comment: I updated my question plz check

Answer (score 0):

Validating by attributes should to keep the current object in valid state not the whole domain/business logic and checking a field to have a unique value is a business rule not an "object rule". (Instantiating a context like this also a bad practise no matter that it is in an attribute or another everyday class.)

Comment: Thanks for your feed back..Any suggestion how to achieve this task?@Peter

Comment: I assume you have a ...Service class which is handling these kind of objects in your domain so create an IsValid method to validate an object. You can add a secondary argument to your method signature to post back the messages to the presentation layer. IHaveValidationErrors interface with methods: void AddError(string msg), AddError(string property, string msg). The logic would be similar to your attribute's logic.